# I set withCredentials is true, but cross-site requests failed in Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

the cross-site url is can access directly, but I can't send cookies to an another pages through cross-site requests.

**Code**

```
export const UserLogin = data => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: USER_LOADING, data: true });
    axios
      .post(`${config.apiPath}/api/user/login`, data, { withCredentials: true })
      .then(function(response) {
        localStorage.setItem("user_agency_mgmt", JSON.stringify(response));
        dispatch({ type: USER_LOADING, data: false });
        return dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN, data: response });
      })
      .catch(function(xhr, status, err) {
        dispatch({ type: USER_LOADING, data: false });
        return dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_FAILURE, error: xhr });
      });
  };
};
```

**Config File**

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";

```
const config = {
  development: {
    apiPath: "https://api.realtor.agency21.rocks",
    domain: "localhost",
    revivePath: "https://revive.graana.rocks",
    lockScreen: true
  },
  production: {
    apiPath: "https://api.realtor.agency21.rocks",
    domain: ".agency21.rocks",
    revivePath: "https://revive.graana.rocks",
    lockScreen: true
  },
  domain: ".agency21.rocks"
};
module.exports = config[env];
```

**Note:** when I changed `apiPath` to `http://localhost:3001` it working fine but when I change path to `https://api.realtor.agency21.rocks` cookies is not working on cross-site